# Assign every TD in PHP While Loop Table a Link

Tags: php, html, forms, action

I have a while loop that retrieves info from the mysql db. Now there is a column called profile. So I want every `<td>` in the profile to be a button that would have an action which would lead to a PHP page. How do I do that?

```
<form action="profile.php" method="get">

while($result)
{
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>';
echo $result['profile'];
echo '</tr>';
echo '</td>';
echo '</table>';
}
```

Now every `$result['profile']` should be a submit like - `<input type="submit">`

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to do an `echo '<input type="submit">';` or am I misunderstanding your question?

Answer (score 1):

rewrite

```
echo $result['profile'];
```

to this code:

```
echo '<a href="profile.php?id='.$result['id'].'">'.$result['name'].'</a>' ;
```

Comment: how do i use the get form element then?

Comment: You don't need the form element if you go this route.

Comment: @ryan A link with parameters **is** a `$_GET`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

```
echo '</tr>';
echo '</td>';
```

should be:

```
echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

To add a Submit button, change

```
echo '<td>';
```

to

```
echo '<td><input type="Submit" value="Submit">';
```

and

```
echo '</td>';
```

to

```
echo '</input></td>';
```

You will need to add the appropriate attributes to the submit button if applicable. Also, you will need to surround the submit button with a `form` element. Whether each link has its own form, or the entire table is surrounded by one is up to you.

**Edit**

To surround the table with a `form` tag, change `echo '<table>';` to `echo '<form><table>';`. Then, change `echo '</table>';` to `echo '</table></form>';`. Submit buttons are automatically "linked" to the `form` element they are contained in. All you have to do is to define the form `action`.

**Edit**

Actually, because you are using a GET request, this entire thing can be simplified by using links instead of forms. So go with RAMe0's answer.

Comment: The entire table is surrounded by one. SO, can you now edit your code to make it one. Thanks

Comment: oh and how to link the submit with the form tag?

Comment: but how to assign the value to $result['profile']; instead of submit

Comment: You need to do that server-side